# Como obter a data/hora atual, independente da do dispositivo?

Tags: java, android

Bem, sei que quando você cria um objeto do tipo Date: `new Date()`, é retornado o horário e data do dispositivo, então se eu chegar em configurações e alterar esses valores, logo a hora retornada estará diferente da hora universal ou local, correta.
Como posso pegar uma hora universal e aplicar o fuso horário da região?

Comment: A sua aplicação necessita do GPS ligado para funcionar?

Comment: Precisa sim, tenho um app similar aos apps de táxi...

Comment: Desculpe, não era GPS mas sim acesso à internet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se tiver acesso à *internet* pode obter a data/hora actual recorrendo a um Public NTP Time Server.

Como o acesso ao serviço é uma operação de rede ela terá de ser feita numa thread que não a UIThread.
Para este caso o mais indicado é usar um IntentService.

**TimeService.java**

```
public class TimeService extends IntentService {

    public static final String RESULT_RECEIVER_EXTRA = "result_receiver_extra";
    public static final String RESULT_DATA_KEY = "result_data_key";
    public static final int SUCCESS_RESULT = 0;
    public static final int FAILURE_RESULT = 1;
    public static final String FAILURE_MESSAGE_KEY = "failure_message_key";

    private final String TIME_SERVER = "time.nist.gov";
    private ResultReceiver resultReceiver;

    public TimeService() {
        super("TimeService");
    }

    //Método para facilitar o uso do Service
    public static void requestTime(@NonNull Context context,
                                   @NonNull ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeService.class);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT_RECEIVER_EXTRA, resultReceiver);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@NonNull Intent intent) {

        resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(RESULT_RECEIVER_EXTRA);
        if(resultReceiver == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No ResultReceiver");
        }
        deliverResultToReceiver(getTime());
    }

    private TimeResult getTime(){

        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = null;
        try {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            return new TimeResult(FAILURE_RESULT, -1, e.getMessage());
        }
        TimeInfo timeInfo = null;
        try {
            timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new TimeResult(FAILURE_RESULT, -1, e.getMessage());
        }
        long time = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
        return new TimeResult(SUCCESS_RESULT, time, "");
    }

    //Usa o ResultReceiver para enviar o resultado
    private void deliverResultToReceiver(TimeResult result){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FAILURE_MESSAGE_KEY, result.failureMessage);
        bundle.putLong(RESULT_DATA_KEY, result.time);
        resultReceiver.send(result.resultCode, bundle);
    }

    private class TimeResult{

        int resultCode;
        String failureMessage;
        long time;

        protected TimeResult(int resultCode, long time, String failureMessage){

            this.resultCode = resultCode;
            this.time = time;
            this.failureMessage = failureMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

O serviço, para comunicar com o NTP Time Server, usa a classe [NTPUDPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/NTPUDPClient.html).
É necessário indicar essa dependência, por isso adicione

```
compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
```

no *builder.gradle* do modulo.

Para usar o IntentService utilize o método

```
public static void requestTime(@NonNull Context context,
                               @NonNull ResultReceiver resultReceiver)
```

O serviço usa o objecto `resultReceiver` para comunicar o resultado.

Exemplo de uma Activity para usar o serviço.

**TimeActivity.java**

```
public class TimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);

        tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    }

    public void onClickGetTime(View view) {
        tvResult.setText("Loading...");
        TimeService.requestTime(this, new TimeResultReceiver(new Handler(), this));
    }

    private static class TimeResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

        private WeakReference<TimeActivity> activityWeakReference;

        public TimeResultReceiver(Handler handler, TimeActivity activity) {
            super(handler);
            activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, @NonNull Bundle resultData) {

            TimeActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                switch (resultCode)
                {
                    case TimeService.SUCCESS_RESULT:
                        long result = resultData.getLong(TimeService.RESULT_DATA_KEY);
                        activity.handleResult(result);
                        break;
                    case TimeService.FAILURE_RESULT:
                        String failureMassage = resultData.getString(TimeService.FAILURE_MESSAGE_KEY);
                        activity.handleFailure(failureMassage);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid result code");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void handleFailure(String failureMassage) {
        tvResult.setText("Error");
        Toast.makeText(this, failureMassage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void handleResult(long result) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date resultDate = new Date(result);
        tvResult.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(resultDate));
    }
}
```

**activity_time.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCalculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Time"
        android:onClick="onClickGetTime"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hora actual: "/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Notas:**

- É necessário a permissão `android.permission.INTERNET`.
- O Time Server usado é o [time.nist.gov](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi). É possível usar outro qualquer.
  Veja [Public NTP Time Server list.](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/WebHome#Browsing_the_Lists)

Answer (score -2):

Na verdade Date() é um timestamp, então internamente ele **já é independente de fuso**. Não é preciso pegar a data de outro serviço da Internet, porque a data/hora do celular é geralmente a mais precisa que você pode conseguir (as torres de celular sincronizam a hora com receptores GPS).

A conversão para o fuso local só acontece quando é convertida para formato humanamente legível. Exemplo:

```
// http://www.coderanch.com/t/417443/java/java/Convert-Date-timezone
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

O seu problema talvez seja que o usuário configura manualmente o fuso horário e ele é diferente do correto para o local em que ele está nesse momento.

Se isso é um problema realmente tão sério, você pode tentar usar a Time Zone API do Google Maps para obter fuso e horário de verão para uma latitude e longitude (que você obteria do GPS do celular).

Comment: O que o AP quer é uma forma de obter a data actual, independente da do dispositivo, pois essa pode ter sido alterada e não estar correcta.