# Detectar ação de intent implícita quando o Sistema Operacional Android mudar manualmente o horário

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Preciso detectar em meu aplicativo quando o usuário mudar manualmente o horário do sistema. Como eu faço isso?

Por exemplo:

Se o usuário reiniciar o dispositivo eu posso detectar este evento com em meu Broadcast receiver assim:

```
if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, Service.class);

        context.startService(pushIntent);
}
```

Agora como faço para detectar mudança de horário.

Comment: é só pegar a [hora do dispositivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239232/como-pegar-a-data-atual-no-android) e a [hora pela internet](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127067/como-obter-a-data-hora-atual-independente-da-do-dispositivo) , depois disso é só comparar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando a data/hora do sistema é alterada é lançado um `android.intent.action.TIME_SET`.

Para o intersectar, registe um receiver no AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

e escreva o respectivo BroadcastReceiver

```
public class TimeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Houve uma alteração na data/hora do sistema

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Muito boa resposta meu amigo. Não é atoa que você mais de 41 mil pontos kkkk